# Using UIWebView links to call a function?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, hyperlink

I'm using a UIWebView to display formatted text from local HTML. Is it possible to have specific links in the HTML call Obj-C functions? For example, clicking a link to have a new view appear? Or am I resigned to using Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [UIWebViewDelegate:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:) to intercept the URL and do something with it. E.g.

```
if ([[request.URL absoluteString]compare:@"http://somelink"] == NSOrderedSame) {
  [self someFunction];
  return YES;  // return NO to prevent this link from loading
}
```